# displaying specific line of .ics/text-file in app

Tags: android

I am trying to display a certain lines of a .ics file. I am treating it as a textfile. Basically I am trying to extract the relevant information. The .ics/text-file contains the following info:

```
  BEGIN:VEVENT
  VERSION:2.0
  DTSTART:20161113T100000Z
  DTEND:20161113T110000Z
  DTSTAMP:20161126T142503Z
  SUMMARY:Breakfast
  DESCRIPTION:
  END:VEVENT
```

I want it to display the date, time and summary on screen. I tried doing this by reading through the file line by line until end of file and store the "20161113" part of line 3 in three intergers: date, month and day. Respectively, 2016, 11 and 13. Also the beginning and ending time part (T1000, T1100) in an integer hhStart=10 and minStart=00 / hhEnd=11 and minEnd=00.

Also I want to take the text of the summary "breakfast".

In the end I just want a simple view in the app where a selected .ics/txt file, containing several in the say way formatted events, are displayed as:

> 13/11/2016:
>
> Breakfast 10:00 - 11:00
>
> appointment dentist 12:00 - 13:00
>
> 14/11/2016:
>
> Lunch with Peter 13:00 - 14:00

etc

please note date format is [dd/mm/yyyy] and 24h cycle is used.

I cannot seem to get an eof() to work within a whileloop.

```
private void loadSavedFile(){
    String TEXT = "test.ics";
    String DTSTART = "DTSTART:";
    String DTEND = "DTEND':";
    String Summary = "SUMMARY";
    
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(TEXT);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new DataInputStream(fis) ) );
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);
        String line;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ){
            editText.append(line);
            editText.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        showFile.setText("Cannot read file");
    }

}
```